# Swift add view to front via appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

Trying to add a subview to the front of the UI via AppDelegate and it's not working. I have a reachability notifier that should add the UIView from a xib when there is no internet connection.

App Delegate code:

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
    if !reachability.isReachable {
        print("APP: Network reachable")
        if networkErrorView != nil {
            networkErrorView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    } else {
        print("ERROR: Network not reachable")
        networkErrorView = NetworkErrorView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: self.window!.frame.height / 4, width: self.window!.frame.width - 60, height: self.window!.frame.height / 2))
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(networkErrorView)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.bringSubview(toFront: networkErrorView)
        print("View is showing")
    }
}
```

The notification does fire and I do get "View is showing" printed to the console. I've tried calling this via `dispatchQueue.main.async` but this just results in an infinite loop which crashes the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private func dismissOfflineScreen() {
    if let navigationVC = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController, navigationVC.viewControllers.first is OfflineViewController {
        navigationVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

private func presentOfflineScreen() {
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: OfflineViewController())
    navigationVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    navigationVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(navigationVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Would a view controller be a better solution than adding a view, easily controllable etc?

Answer (score 0):

in the else try to access the current viewController :

```
if let currentViewController = self.window?.rootViewController {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    networkErrorView = NetworkErrorView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: (screenSize.height / 4), width: (screenSize.width - 60), height: (screenSize.height / 2)))
    currentViewController.view.addSubview(networkErrorView)
    currentViewController.view.bringSubview(toFront: networkErrorView)
}
```

Comment: Tried this approach and had the same issue.

Comment: @user1888564 is your comment : print("View is showing") is still visible in log? I have edited with UIScreen.main.bounds for UIView size.